# How to MOLE the DataContext

Tags: linq-to-sql, datacontext, moles

I'm trying to figure out how to mole the datacontext so that my unit tests never hit the database.

What I want to achieve is that a datacontext is created  but doesn't connect to a db and then when I call GetTable (via my repository) I return a List.AsQueryable() (that I create myself in the unit test).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue here: http://dimecasts.net/Content/WatchEpisode/170